# SET bit 32 in a INT data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to update a `INT` data type column managing bits based on a sub-query result. 
Everything works, but if I try to set the 32th bit, SQL Server fires an overflow error. My query is something like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = POWER(2, MySubQuery.MyBit) FROM (SELECT MyBit FROM MySubTable WHERE ...)
```

The `INT` data type is signed, so I acccept that if MyBit value is 31, the result of `MyColumn` is something like "-2147483648", but instead it fires the overflow error.

This also also if I try to do this simple test:

```
select POWER(2, 31)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Use `bigint`. The maximum value of an `int` in SQL Server is `2,147,483,647`. `2^31` is `2,147,483,648` (1 more than the maximum), thus it can't be allocated to a `int`.

Comment: [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql)

Comment: Cast to bigint, do the bit operations, cast back to int.

Comment: You'll have to use the ungainly `CASE MyBit WHEN 31 THEN -2147483648 ELSE POWER(2, MyBit) END` -- and that's only meaningful if you *insist* on having bit 32 available (that is, it's an external thing and not something you willfully put in your database design).

Comment: Personally, I would do what @Ben suggested: `SELECT POWER(CONVERT(bigint,2),31);` works fine, as `POWER` will return a `bigint`. This also means you have your options open for larger powers, if needed. Future proofing is *normally* a good idea. :)

Comment: I need to use the SIGNED INT, can't use BIG INT: that column must be managed by an old VB6 application, that can test bits just on SIGNED INT data type

Comment: @Ben can't do cast to bigint then back to int, if you try this: SELECT CONVERT(int, POWER(CONVERT(bigint,2),31))...  sql return error

Comment: Incidentally, due to T-SQL's arcane rules for implicit conversion and promotion, `CASE MyBit WHEN 31 THEN 0x80000000 ELSE POWER(2, MyBit) END` also works and might be a bit more obvious. You could even write out all bits that way, though I doubt it's faster than using `POWER`. No base 2 literals, alas. And no bit shifting, of course.

Comment: @user3518663, with a signed int, bit 32 is the sign bit and negative values are in [twos-compliment form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). So bit 32 must always be zero for a bitmask to work as expected with a 32-bit int.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this correctly, you might use a bitwise OR:

```
DECLARE @bit32 INT = -2147483648; --only highest bit is set
SELECT CAST(@bit32 AS binary(4));
DECLARE @int2 INT=100;
SELECT CAST(@int2 AS binary(4));
SELECT @int2 | @bit32;
SELECT CAST(@int2 | @bit32 AS binary(4));
```

Returns

```
0x80000000
0x00000064
-2147483548
0x80000064
```

You can set (or unset) any bit with this approach.

Read about [bitwise operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql)

### Update: Some examples

Set masks

```
DECLARE @bit3 INT=POWER(2,3)
DECLARE @bit4 INT=POWER(2,4)
DECLARE @bit5 INT=POWER(2,5)
SELECT @bit5 | @bit3
```

--Returns

```
40 --which is binary "00101000" (bit count starts with 0)
```

--Which bit is set?

```
SELECT 40 & @bit3 --returns 8
      ,40 & @bit4 --returns 0
```

Comment: `VARBINARY(32)` is a bit overkill for something that logically fits a `BINARY(4)`. Note bytes, not bits. (If you really wanted to set an arbitrary bit in a `VARBINARY(32)`, you're looking at much more involved code than `POWER`. Fortunately that's not a requirement here.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ups, was so fixed to the number 32 :-D, thx, edited my answer